# Can not run wkhtmltoimage, shared library missing libXrender.so.1

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

When I run the i386 version of wkhtmlimage (on Ubuntu 64 bit if that matters), I get the following error,

> ./wkhtmltoimage-i386 http://www.google.com google.jpg
>   ./wkhtmltoimage-i386: error while loading shared libraries: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The thing is that I have installed the libxrender-dev package already and the libXrender.so.1 can be found at /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1.

I can't see what's wrong, so if anyone have encountered this problem before please let me know.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

May be wkhtmltoimage-i386 is not for 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions issue. Assign higher permissions to the folder your wkhtml resides or to where it's putting images